# Finding the sum of all elements of a list in list which has characters in 1 line

Tags: python-2.7, list

```
ab = [ ['5','6','7','8','9','10'],['1','2','3'],['3','4','5']]
print sum([sum(int(x) for x in y for y in ab])])
```

I have to find the sum of all elements in ab with a single print statement. I'm trying to convert each element of each of the lists to int and creating a list which has sum of each individual list.
I get a syntax error and not sure how to do it.

Comment: `print sum(int(x) for y in ab for x in y)`

Comment: for `reduce` fans:  `reduce(lambda x, y: int(x)+int(y),reduce(list.__add__,ab))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the `for` loop for x (the inner loop) before the `for` loop for y (the outer loop). That is why it is not working. What you need is `print sum(int(x) for y in ab for x in y)`
Also it might be better to use a generator here because you are not reusing the list, since it is more efficient.